# How do I build a Laravel cache driver that uses Cloudflare Workers KV as a data store?

Tags: laravel, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

By default it looks like Laravel requires cache drivers to be defined in a "table". Standard cache drivers are of course - file, memcached, redis, etc.

Cloudflare Workers with Cloudflare Workers KV is a compute + key/value pair storage system which I'd like to use for caching purposes (i.e. write to Workers KV from Laravel, but fetch items from the edge). This maximizes cache performance, since any cached requests can be handled by the Cloudflare Worker, with the cache being at the edge as well. In other words, no request ever makes it to our API at the origin, if cached. It also saves us having to create origins in AWS all across the world, or even do things like database replication to factor for speed-of-light latency for API consumers worldwide.

I want to build a cache driver that uses Cloudflare KV for the [REST API](https://go.tallyfy.com/api/) of our SaaS product, [Tallyfy](https://tallyfy.com). This would give us the kind of ass-kicking performance and security benefits our customers want/deserve. How would I go about doing this, exactly?

Comment: You might want to start reading [Adding Custom Cache Drivers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache#adding-custom-cache-drivers) from the documentation

Comment: What's your telegram, are you still working on this?

Comment: Just realized that this is useless without the compute itself (Laravel execution) also living at the edge :)

Comment: Once this [PR](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-php/pull/139) gets merged, the Cloudflare PHP API will start supporting KV.